# android: Bitmap decodeFile by filepath returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, file, bitmap, bitmapfactory

After user has chosen a picture from gallery, the picture was showing correctly in the imageview `imgview`. Code as follows:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {
            adapter.clear();
            single_path = data.getStringExtra("single_path");
            imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + single_path, imgview);
            image_picked = true;
        } 
    }

    public void Upload_new_image() 
    {
        if (image_picked == true)
        {
            String imgFilePath = "file://" + single_path;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(""+imgFilePath);       
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);     // Line 156: NPE
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("upload.png", image);
            file.saveInBackground();
            ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("photo_database");
            imgupload.saveInBackground();
            Constants.custom_toast(this, "Image uploaded", "");         
        }
        else
        {
            Constants.custom_toast(this, "No image is picked!", "");
        }
```

### Logcat:

```
10-04 15:18:31.926: W/dalvikvm(20254): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c77700)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.abc.app.activity.User_pick_image.Upload_new_image(User_pick_image.java:156)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.abc.app.activity.User_pick_image.onOptionsItemSelected(User_pick_image.java:93)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2640)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1171)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:630)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:200)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
10-04 15:18:31.931: E/AndroidRuntime(20254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Question:

While the image can be properly displayed in `imgview` by the imagerLoad.displayImage method, when pressed for uploading the image via the `Upload_new_image()` method, the same file link to the same file cannot be fetched and error arised as in the logcat.

### Information:

I have obtained the value for `single_path` by picking difference images, the full value was in the format below:
`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_xxx.png`

How could that be solved?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which statement is on line 156? Which pointer is null? Please tell what the function should do. You did not tell.

Comment: the line `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);   ` as marked in the above code

Comment: How could i see that? You have to scroll to see it.

Comment: Ignore this. Checking something atm.

Comment: Remove the "file://" at the start and try File file = new File(path); then file.exists() or file.isFile(), see what they return. also verify the file path has an extension for image, those are the requirements to ensure that a BitmapFactory.decodeFile will work 100%. If the above returns a false, then probably there is a problem with the path.

Comment: @Nightware: thanks for your continuous follow up. I have tried `File file = new File(path); then file.exists()`, it returns true for `file.exists()`. Replacing by `String imgFilePath = single_path;`, the NPE disappears, yet image file fails to be uploaded to parse (only other photo descriptions in string can be uploaded properly, ie. parse setting is correct)

Comment: Try to put this line before saving the ParseObject:

`imgupload.put("image", file);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String imgFilePath = "file://" + single_path;
```

Should be:

```
 String imgFilePath = single_path;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! the NPE does not pop anymore...I do not know whether the following is another question, just to mention some details: now the toast `Image uploaded` is shown, the `if` loop is completed, but no image is shown in Parse database. (the parse setting is ensured correct because remaining info like image title in string (not shown here) other the image file  can be properly uploaded to parse). All in all, thanks for solving the first NPE problem! If then I should mark this as correct

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the value of single_path. Maybe you should add "/" before imgFilePath:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/"+imgFilePath);
```

Comment: thanks...tried but still return the same NPE error at same line~

Comment: I have obtained the value for single_path by picking difference images, the full value was in the format below: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_xxx.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this, get the Uri from the data intent like this:

`Uri contactUri = data.getData();`

Then you should get your absolute path from that Uri.

// Edit 
This might be of help:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri)
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try
    {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know but I can't confirm if he has the correct path, that's why I posted the above. If it still doesn't work for him, then he's crashing somewhere else, not in the fileDecode method.

Comment: He is crashing exactly in decodeFile(). Ok. Not crashing but that returns the null.

Answer (score 0):

Also there could be reason that one has not added runtime permission for reading external storage, which may lead to this type of error.So please check this permission is granted or not from your settings in app info.

**Note:**
Settings of your app may have storage option disabled which needs to enabled.